# Is there any way that I can connect to my live database server and insert data into it?

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

I am facing problem while inserting data in my live database server. My current connection code is:

```
import pymysql

host="192.224.256.***"
user_name="user"
password= "pass"
database="checkDatabase"

try:
    connection = pymysql.connect(host, user_name, password, database)
    print("connection established")

except:
      print("connection failed")
```

result is ::  connection failed..

Is there any way that I can connect to my live database server and insert data into it?

Comment: A connection to a database can fail for lots of reasons. Your question doesn't have enough information. Try checking error messages.

Comment: pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'user'@'39.59.10.66' (using password: YES)")  :: I have given all permissions to the user

Comment: You haven't given permission to the user "user" to access your database from that IP. I don't remember the exact procedure to do so, you should check the mysql documentation.

Comment: How do you know the connection is failed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should connect like this :

```
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='user', passwd='password', db='database')
```

Or like this :

```
db_name = "database"
db = pymysql.connect("localhost", "user", "password", "db_name")
```

Eather way you need the quotes so you cant just add strings the way you did it.